# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : unable to cast between types in SeedData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core 5 to create a to do list and I"m trying to incorporate my seed data.

This is my model class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace To_Do_List.Models
{
    public class To_Do
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        // Setting requirements for attributes as shown below:

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength=3)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Title must begin with a capital letter and be a minimum 3 characters long with a maximum of 60 characters.")] // Requires first letter to be a capital letter, allows other text to be written afterwards, \s matches any whitespace characters
        [Required] // Indicates property must have a value
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        public int priority { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Completed?")]
        public bool checkbox { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my `seeddata.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using To_Do_List.Data;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using To_Do_List.Models;

namespace To_Do_List.Models;

public static class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var context = new To_Do_ListContext(
            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<
                DbContextOptions<To_Do_ListContext>>()))
        {
            // Look for any tasks
            if (context.To_Do.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            context.To_Do.AddRange(
                new To_Do
                {
                    Title = "test",
                    Description = "this is a test",
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-4-22"),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-4-28"),
                    checkbox = true,
                    priority = 3
                }
            );
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'

I'm fairly certain it's my priority variable that is having an issue since converting the type of priority to a string and changing the seed data accordingly allows the application to work.

I appreciate any help for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait I found out the issue. I forgot to migrate the database to the new data types above.

This can be done by editing the database via the Nuget package manager and typing:

```
Add-Migration migration_name
Update-Database
```

Such that migration_name is the name of the new migration.

Comment: Consider adding some details. Some other people may encounter the same problem. You can accept your own answer too.

Comment: Noted, I'm updating the answer.